# Что будет являться сказуемым?

Tags: синтаксис

"Язык - величайшее средство общения".

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что подлежащее здесь ЯЗЫК, сказуемое выражено цельным словосочетанием СРЕДСТВО ОБЩЕНИЯ. Составное именное сказуемое.
Если поменять местами части предложения (Величайшее средство общения - язык), тогда сказуемым будет слово ЯЗЫК.

Comment: Это очень спорный прием - инверсия членов.
Я думаю здесь имеет место т.н. синтасическая многозначность без многозначности семантической, т.ею ситуация когда одно предложения допускает два способа грамматического разбора без существенных различий в смысловом толковании.
Но в русском языке в подобных случаях "по умолчанию" подлежащим принято считать член, идущий первым. так что по сути я согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Не вполне согласен с тем, что в этом предложении при изменении порядка слов меняется их синтаксическая роль. Подлежащее - это предмет речи, то, о чем говорится в предложении. Предмет речи здесь язык, как бы мы ни располагали слова. Так что в любом случае сказуемое этого предложения - "средство". Можно подумать о том, чтобы дополнить сказуемое словом "величайшее", ибо это прилагательное тесно связано со сказуемым и по смыслу входит в состав сказуемого. А вот слово "общения" вполне можно рассматривать как дополнение

Comment: Роль вообще говоря действительно не должна меняться. Но в тех случаях, когда она неопределена, её искусственно доопределяют, основываясь именно на порядке членов. 
Сравните: "Любовь означает верность".

Comment: Согласна с Виктором насчет дополнения. Основа: язык - средство. Вообще есть определенные типы цельных словосочетаний.

Comment: сказуемое - средство общения, цельное сочетание. Не средство же для мытья головы.

Comment: Согласна с doom, конечно, это средство общения, а не средство для похудения